# VBA find approximative header name

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to use a find to find me a header. The issue is that the header may have small variation (maybe an extra space or one of the words in plural). Therefore I would like it to find approximate matches. Anyone knows how? Thanks! This is my VBA:

```
With Sheets("Sheet0").Range("A1:BB1")
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet0").Range("A1:BB1").Find(What:="How would you rate the technical quality of today's presentation?", _
        lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If (Not rng Is Nothing) Then
        rng.EntireColumn.Cut Destination:=Sheets("Sheet0").Columns("P:P")
    Else
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Without precise definition of *"small variation"* this is impossible to answer...

Comment: If it is just `space` and `Plural`, then yes this can be answered (though it would required complex combinations of words) but if typos come into picture or different words then yes it may be impossible.

Comment: "small variations" means 2 words in different order, plurals, etc. If there is a way to say: "Find me THIS header, otherwise the header that is closest to that header"